# Problem of gcc when i want pip3 install hunspell

Tags: macos, gcc, pip, homebrew, hunspell

I am working on mac OS. 
I used "brew install hunspell" but now I have a problem to make "pip3 install hunspell"

I tried brew install gcc but it doenst' solve the problem.

```
MacBook:bin $ pip3 install hunspell
Collecting hunspell
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e5/fe/cfc4dfd92c3a37c34d2806d5b84f9981bf3520db20149f8ee1a61f6fc69d/hunspell-0.5.5.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: hunspell
Building wheel for hunspell (setup.py) ... error
Complete output from command /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7 -u -c"importsetuptools,tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/ty/z084vbf1137qft9t7nmh8xr0000gq/T/pip-install-f00b6zkx/hunspell/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/ty/z084vbf1137cqft9t7nmh8xr0000gq/T/pip-wheel-ssonog8z --python-tag cp37:
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_ext
building 'hunspell' extension
creating build
creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7
/usr/local/bin/gcc-6 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wa,-q -D_LINUX -I/usr/local/Cellar/hunspell/1.6.2/include/hunspell -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c hunspell.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/hunspell.o -Wall
unable to execute '/usr/local/bin/gcc-6': No such file or directory
error: command '/usr/local/bin/gcc-6' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Failed building wheel for hunspell
Running setup.py clean for hunspell
Failed to build hunspell
Installing collected packages: hunspell
Running setup.py install for hunspell ... error
Complete output from command /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/ty/z084vbf1137cqft9t7nmh8xr0000gq/T/pip-install-f00b6zkx/hunspell/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/ty/z084vbf1137cqft9t7nmh8xr0000gq/T/pip-record-7vvt6eyr/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
running install
running build
running build_ext
building 'hunspell' extension
creating build
creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7
/usr/local/bin/gcc-6 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wa,-q -D_LINUX -I/usr/local/Cellar/hunspell/1.6.2/include/hunspell -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c hunspell.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/hunspell.o -Wall
unable to execute '/usr/local/bin/gcc-6': No such file or directory
error: command '/usr/local/bin/gcc-6' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/ty/z084vbf1137cqft9t7nmh8xr0000gq/T/pip-install-f00b6zkx/hunspell/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/ty/z084vbf1137cqft9t7nmh8xr0000gq/T/pip-record-7vvt6eyr/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/ty/z084vbf1137cqft9t7nmh8xr0000gq/T/pip-install-f00b6zkx/hunspell/
```

Comment: Is this the  output you get with gcc installed via brew? Obviously, there's no `/usr/local/bin/gcc-6` file, which brew expects to be there.

Comment: @VladislavIvanishin this is the output when i make "pip3 install hunspell". I have already done "brew install hunspell", and it worked.
Yes there is no gcc-6 (but i have gcc-9), but I don't know how to redirect it to gcc-9 ? (is it at least possible ?)

Answer (score 1):

You have to install [gcc 6](https://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/gcc-6/) with:

```
brew install gcc@6
```

Comment: I tried different things before and now my error is :
hunspell.cpp:20:10: fatal error: 'hunspell.hxx' file not found
  #include <hunspell.hxx>
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  1 error generated.
  error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1